# How to draw complex shape from code behind for custom control in resource dictionary

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, resourcedictionary, controltemplates

I am new to wpf and am having a problem which may or may not be trivial. I have defined a custom control as follows in the resource dictionary:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="SyringeSlider.Themes.Generic"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SyringeSlider">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Canvas Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"  Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Name="syringeCanvas">

                        </Canvas>
                    </Border>                   
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Unfortunately I cannot go beyond this because I would like to draw a geometry onto the canvas consisting of a set of multiple line geometries whose dimensions are calculated as a function of the space available in the canvas. I believe that I need a code behind method to do this, but have not been able to determine how to link the xaml definition to a code behind method.

Note that I have set up a class x:Class="SyringeSlider.Themes.Generic" for specifically this purpose, but can't figure out which Canvas property to link the drawing method to.

My drawing method looks like this

```
private void CalculateSyringe()
        {
            int adjHeight = (int) Height - 1;
            int adjWidth = (int) Width - 1;

            // Calculate some very useful values based on the chart above.
            int borderOffset = (int)Math.Floor(m_borderWidth / 2.0f);
            int flangeLength = (int)(adjHeight * .05f);

            int barrelLeftCol = (int)(adjWidth * .10f);
            int barrelLength = (int)(adjHeight * .80);
            int barrelRightCol = adjWidth - barrelLeftCol;

            int coneLength = (int)(adjHeight * .10);

            int tipLeftCol = (int)(adjWidth * .45);
            int tipRightCol = adjWidth - tipLeftCol;
            int tipBotCol = adjWidth - borderOffset;

            Path mySyringePath = new Path();
            PathGeometry mySyringeGeometry = new PathGeometry();
            PathFigure mySyringeFigure = new PathFigure();
            mySyringeFigure.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
            Point pointA = new Point(0, flangeLength);
            mySyringeFigure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(pointA, true));
            Point pointB = new Point();
            pointB.Y = pointA.Y + barrelLength;
            pointB.X = 0;
            mySyringeFigure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(pointB, true));

            // You get the idea....Add more points in this way

            mySyringeGeometry.Figures.Add(mySyringeFigure);
            mySyringePath.Data = mySyringeGeometry;

        }
```

SO my question is:

1) Does what I am trying to do make any sense?
2) Can a use a canvas for this purpose? If not, what are my other options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a custom control and creating a template, override the OnApplyTemplate() function in your control's code. There you have to search for template parts and then you get the references in your code.

Something like this.

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    private Canvas myCanvas;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        Canvas theCanvas = Template.FindName("syringeCanvas", this) as Canvas;

        if(theCanvas != null)
        {
            //<-- Save a reference to the canvas
            myCanvas = theCanvas;

            //<-- Do some stuff.
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to name your canvas in the xaml.